# webView in Fragment to Upload File (like image)

Tags: android, image, webview, upload, fragment

I've several combinations of codes, but I still can't find a way to able to make the upload image functioning. I have given permission for the camera, write and read storage. I think the problem is the Java code. Below is my current java fragment code. I hope some of you can help me how to make the code below functioning while able to upload photo/ use camera or files.

[image: Photo of Upload Button needed to be functioning]

**Current Java Code:**

```
 public class DashboardFragment extends Fragment {

     public DashboardFragment() {

     }

     WebView webView2;
     String url = "https://gcs-bn.com/my-account/edit-account/";


     public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                              ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
     {

         View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false);
         webView2 = (WebView)v.findViewById(R.id.webView2);
         webView2.loadUrl(url);
         WebSettings settings = webView2.getSettings();
         settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
         webView2.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
         return v;
     }


     private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient{
         @Override
         public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
         }

         @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
         @Override
         public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
             if (url.startsWith("mailto:")) {
                 //Handle mail Urls
                 startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse(url)));
             } else if (url.startsWith("tel:")) {
                 //Handle telephony Urls
                 startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(url)));
             } else {
                 view.loadUrl(url);
             }
             return true;
         }

         @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
         @Override
         public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
             final Uri uri = request.getUrl();
             if (uri.toString().startsWith("mailto:")) {
                 //Handle mail Urls
                 startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri));
             } else if (uri.toString().startsWith("tel:")) {
                 //Handle telephony Urls
                 startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, uri));
             } else {
                 //Handle Web Urls
                 view.loadUrl(uri.toString());
             }
             return true;
         }
     } }
```

Answer (score 0):

[here](https://github.com/delight-im/Android-AdvancedWebView) is best webview libary that manage maximum functionality.